# Alternative to SendKeys "{Esc}" for unbound text box Undo

Tags: ms-access, sendkeys

I have an **unbound** textbox control.  The user enters some valid text and leaves the control.  The user then returns to the control and enters some invalid text.  I want to show the user a message then **rollback the value of the control to its previous state** and **keep the focus in that control**.

I've tried the following approaches, none of which gets me exactly what I am looking for:

---

**OPTION A**: SendKeys

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = DataIsInvalid(Me.MyTextBox.Value)
    If Cancel Then SendKeys "{Esc}"
End Sub
```

This does exactly what I want, but I really want to avoid using `SendKeys`.  There are many problems that come with using SendKeys: [Vista+ compatibility](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/SendInput/), keys being sent to a different application, etc.

---

**OPTION B**: Undo method of control

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = DataIsInvalid(Me.MyTextBox.Value)
    If Cancel Then Me.MyTextBox.Undo
End Sub
```

This is simply broken for unbound controls (at least as of MS Access 2002/XP).  This method does not restore the value of MyTextBox to the valid input.  However, it does allow the user to change the focus to a new control while leaving the invalid input in place in Me.MyTextBox!  Unbelievable!!!

---

**OPTION C**: Undo method of form

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = DataIsInvalid(Me.MyTextBox.Value)
    If Cancel Then Me.Form.Undo
End Sub
```

The `Undo` here does absolutely nothing.  But at least it doesn't break the BeforeUpdate Cancel=True code and allow the invalid data to stand.

---

**OPTION D**: Explicitly restore old value in BeforeUpdate event

```
Private mPrevMyTextBoxValue As Variant

Private Sub MyTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    mPrevMyTextBoxValue = Me.MyTextBox.Value
End Sub
Private Sub MyTextBox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = DataIsInvalid(Me.MyTextBox.Value)
    If Cancel Then Me.MyTextBox.Value = mPrevMyTextBoxValue
    'If Cancel Then Me.MyTextBox.Text = mPrevMyTextBoxValue
End Sub
```

Attempts to assign the previous value to either the `.Value` or `.Text` property of the textbox result in the same error message:

> The macro or function set to the BeforeUpdate or ValidationRule property for this field is preventing {Program Name} from saving the data in the field.

---

**OPTION E**: Explicitly restore old value in AfterUpdate event

```
Private mPrevMyTextBoxValue As Variant

Private Sub MyTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    If DataIsInvalid(Me.MyTextBox.Value) Then
        Me.MyTextBox.Value = mPrevMyTextBoxValue
        Me.MyTextBox.SetFocus
    Else
        mPrevMyTextBoxValue = Me.MyTextBox.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This is really close to the desired behavior.  Unfortunately, it's impossible to keep the focus on the control because the AfterUpdate event runs *before* the Tab/Enter keypress or mouse-click events are processed.  So even if we try to force the focus to the proper control (via the `.SetFocus` statement above), the program will immediately shift the focus to the control the user selected.

---

It seems to me that the "right" way to do this is to use the `.Undo` method of the control.  That does not work for unbound controls, though.  This is an inexplicable shortcoming, especially given the fact that an Escape key-press performs this functionality for an unbound field.

Is there a better way to do this or should I just stick to using `SendKeys`?

Comment: Automatically rolling back to the previous value is the stickler.  Could you settle for notifying the user when the value is invalid, keeping the focus in the text box, and allowing the user to choose between inputting a new valid value or pressing ESC to roll back to the previous value?

Comment: Option D would definitely be my choice but unfortunately Microsoft's answer to this is to Sendkeys as per: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128195

Comment: @HansUp: That's the approach I usually take.  In this case, I'd really like to force the previous value without user intervention.

Comment: @HansUp: And, of course, users don't read message boxes even if they are short and direct.  I've stood over users' shoulders and watched them get the same error over and over.  Each time a message box pops up that tells them how to resolve the error.  Each time they close it before reading it so that they can just keep going.  Invariably they turn to me and ask why it won't work.  I then politely tell them to slow down and RTFM.

Comment: @Newd: Thanks for that link.  It adds a bit of official support in favor of just using SendKeys.

Comment: @mwolfe02 If you want to see something interesting, try your Option E, but set focus to another control then back to your textbox. I will post what I mean down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting to page 3 on google I decided to just muck around and see what sort of ordering happens when trying your Option E.  Below is the best workaround method I was able to use to get focus to "Stay" on the textbox in question.

```vb
Private mPrevMyTextBoxValue As Variant

Private Sub Text0_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Text0.Value = 0 Then
        Me.Text0.Value = mPrevMyTextBoxValue
        Me.Text12.SetFocus
        Me.Text0.SetFocus
    Else
        mPrevMyTextBoxValue = Me.Text0.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

0 simulates that it failed the validation.  It seems like if you set focus to something else before setting it back to the textbox you are working with it will stay there.  I don't have an answer as to why unfortunately.

Edit:  I have decided to try to program my theory as to how this works.

```vb
Private blnGoToNextControl as Boolean

Private Function SetFocus(ctrl As control)

   blnGoToNextControl = True
   If ctrl.HasFocus = True Then 
    'Do nothing
   Else 
      ctrl.HasFocus = True 
      blnGoToNextControl = False
   End If
End Function
```

This is my idea of how the SetFocus function works. So then after the AfterUpdate event runs it would check to see if the flag to go to next control is and see that it is set to false and not go to the next control.

Rough coding obviously but hopefully this gets my theory across?

Comment: Wow, that is not at all what I expected would happen.

Comment: Any thoughts on why this works?  I know you said you don't have an answer why, but do you have any theories?

Comment: My theory is that when you set focus it does a check to see if that control already has focus.  If it does then it simply skips the request.  Once it skips the request the flag to "Go to next tab order" stays set as true.  After the function it goes to the next tab.  So when you go away and come back it sets the flag to false and keeps it at the control you had just set focus on.  I realize this just basically reads like a jumble of words but hopefully my explanation makes sense.

Comment: I decided to try to visualize this with some code mentioned in the main body of my answer.

Comment: Actually, that does make sense.  It also explains why doing a `Me.Form.SetFocus` does not work as a substitute for `Me.Text12.SetFocus`.

Comment: Thanks for posting the question, it was a lot of fun trying to figure out.  Sorry the best I could provide was a workaround, but at least now you don't have to use the poison that is SendKeys.  Out of curiosity, has your numlock been randomly turning off?

Comment: Yes, my numlock has turned off at least once. Why do you ask?

Comment: Sendkeys... took me a month when I first started programming in access to tell that my numlock was getting turned off by SendKeys.  I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Karl Peterson's [SendKeys alternative](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/SendInput/) does not seem to suffer from the NumLock problem.  It is also compatible with Windows Vista and later operating systems.  I highly recommend it for those times you are forced to use SendKeys.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that.   Fortunately I have been able to successfully avoid it thus far but at least I can add that to my tool box in case I need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If it is unbound, why not use the AfterUpdate event:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    If DataIsInvalid(Me!MyTextBox.Value) Then
        Me!MyTextBox.Value = Null
        Me!MyTextBox.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

or modify your other solution:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_AfterUpdate()

    Static mPrevMyTextBoxValue As Variant

    If IsEmpty(mPrevMyTextBoxValue) Then
        mPrevMyTextBoxValue = Null
    End If

    If DataIsInvalid(Me!MyTextBox.Value) Then
        Me!MyTextBox.Value = mPrevMyTextBoxValue 
        Me!MyTextBox.SetFocus
    Else
        mPrevMyTextBoxValue = Me!MyTextBox.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Try moving the focus off the textbox, then back:

```
        Me!MyTextBox.Value = mPrevMyTextBoxValue 
        Me!SomeOtherControl.SetFocus
        Me!MyTextBox.SetFocus
```

That someothercontrol can be a tiny nearly hidden textbox.

Comment: That's "Option E" in my question.  It won't work because we can't force the focus back to the MyTextBox control.  That's because MS Access processes the related events and code in the following order:  user presses Tab/Enter --> BeforeUpdate runs --> AfterUpdate runs --> focus shifts to next control.  The problem is that Access sets the focus to the next control *after* the AfterUpdate process runs.  So while Access will honor the request to SetFocus to the MyTextBox control, it will then immediately shift focus to the other control the user requested prior to the AfterUpdate.  Make sense?